# Closed Paths on Hexagonal Lattice

Tags: random-walk, integer-lattices, vector-lattices

I am trying to prove the following asymptotic formula for $a_n$, the number of closed paths of length $n$ on the hexagonal lattice (paths starting and ending at the same hexagon):
$$a_n\sim \frac{6^n \sqrt{3}}{2\pi n}$$

I have already proven an analogous formula for a square lattice using binomial coefficients. Does anyone know of an elementary/intuitive way to prove the above?

Even better, if anyone knows of a way to prove the exact formula
$$a_n=\sum_{i=0}^n (-2)^{n-i}\binom{n}{i}\sum_{j=0}^i \binom{i}{j}^3$$
I can probably figure out how to derive the asymptotic formula from this.

Both of these formulae can be found on OEIS. The sequence $a_n$ is A002898.

Comment: The paper 'closed paths whose steps are nth roots of unity' by Labelle and Lacasse proves the asymptotic formula. In fact, the $n=6$ entry in table 4 is a tighter bound. The paper also gives an exact formula for $a_n$ (referred to as $U_6$ in the paper) in section 2. I don't know how to derive the formula given here and on OEIS from the one in the paper. https://www.dmtcs.org/dmtcs-ojs/index.php/proceedings/article/view/dmAO0153/3610.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to prove the exact formula you mention, but there is a straightforward way to get the asymptotic expression.  As mentioned in OEIS, $a_n$ is the coefficient of $1$ in the expression $(x+1/x+y+1/y+x/y+y/x)^n$.  Let $n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4, n_5, n_6$ be the number of times that $x, 1/x, y, 1/y, x/y, y/x$ respectively occurs in the above expression.  The 6 $n_i$ must all be non-negative integers, and we have the following 3 constraint equations:

$n_1+ n_2+ n_3+ n_4+ n_5+ n_6 = n$, the total number of steps is $n$,

$n_1-n_2+n_5-n_6=0$, the net power of $x$ is $0$,

$n_3-n_4-n_5+n_6=0$, the net power of $y$ is $0$.

We can choose $n_1, n_2, n_3$ to be independent variables, with:

$n_4=n_1-n_2+n_3$

$n_5=(n-3n_1+n_2-2n_3)/2$, and

$n_6=(n-n_1-n_2-2n_3)/2$.

In order that $n_5, n_6$ be integral we need $n-n_1-n_2$ be an even integer.

We can put $a_n=\sum_{n_i} n!/(n_1!n_2!n_3!n_4!n_5!n_6!)$, where the sum over $n_i$ is subject to the constraint equations.

To obtain an asymptotic formula, we use Sterling's asymptotic expression for the factorials:

$n!\sim (2\pi n)^{1/2}n^ne^{-n}$, and we replace the sums by integrals.  The maximum for the multinomial occurs when all $n_i$ are equal to $n/6$, we have $n!/(n/6)!^6 \sim (2\pi n)^{-5/2}6^{n+3}$.  We put $n_1=n/6+x_1$,  $n_2=n/6+x_2$, $n_3=n/6+x_3$, $n_4=n/6+x_1-x_2+x_3$,   $n_5=n/6+(-3x_1+x_2-2x_3)/2$,  and  $n_6=n/6+(-x_1-x_2-2x_3)/2$. The second derivative of $log((n/6+x)!)$ with respect to $x$ is $6/n$.  Carrying out the six second order partial derivatives we get $n!/(n_1!n_2!n_3!n_4!n_5!n_6!)\sim n!/((n/6)!^6Exp[\frac{-1}{2}\frac{6}{n}\begin{pmatrix}x_1 & x_2 & x_3\end{pmatrix}M\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}$, where

$M=\begin{pmatrix}9/2 & -3/2 & 3 \\ -3/2 & 5/2 & -1 \\ 3 & -1 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$

Doing the Gaussian integral gives $(2\pi n)^{3/2}6^{-3/2}/Determinant[M]$.  There is an additional factor of $1/2$ because $n-n_1-n_2$ must be an even integer and so only $1/2$ the points in the sum over $n_1$ and $n_2$ count.  The determinant of $M$ is $18$.  Putting all these factors together we get $\frac{6^n \sqrt 3 }{2 \pi n}$.

Comment: Sorry, but I’m not familiar with this technique. How did you come up with the entries in this matrix? I get that you’re creating a multidimensional taylor expansion of this function about its maximum, but I don’t understand where all of these coefficients are coming from.

Comment: Nevermind, I get it now. Thanks so much for the answer!

Comment: This might be a stretch, but do you know of a good way to derive an analogous formula for the Cairo pentagonal tiling? This method won’t work in such a straightforward way since the same “moves” are not available from each pentagon (because they are in different orientations).